# Time Machine - List of Files that were backed up

Tags: macos, time-machine, time-capsule, logs

I'd like to know to see which files are getting backed up by my time machine? I often see a large amount of data being transfered and I'm not sure sure what it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use tmutil to figure out which files just got deleted?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24446/how-can-i-use-tmutil-to-figure-out-which-files-just-got-deleted)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The command `tmutil compare` lets you compare file lists if you don't want to do it using `ls` or other commands that can show differences in files and folders like `rsync` and many graphical diff programs.

You can list backup paths and then copy them into the compare command. Example:

```
sudo tmutil listbackups
sudo tmutil compare "path1" "path2"
```

Many people adore [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) as well. It makes a powerful database of what files are included with each backup interval.

Comment: Thanks! i'll try it out when I'm by my TimeCapsule) I think this is exactly what I was looking for))

Comment: Why not edit the question a bit to make it more clear what you were wanting. It'll likely get you some up votes if you care for it and put a real title on it rather than a fragment of a phrase.

Comment: A zero cost alternative to BackupLoupe is [TimeTracker](http://www.charlessoft.com/). Does the job well enough for me.

Comment: Honorable mention goes to [timedog](https://github.com/nlfiedler/timedog) open source utility.

Comment: `tmutil compare` was very slow and showed me files that were not changed between backups - timedog was much better.

Answer (score 32):

If you're interested in seeing what files are being read as the backup happens, you can use this command:

```
sudo opensnoop -n backupd | grep -v 'Time Machine Backups'
```

Note:  the above worked in earlier versions of macOS.  In High Sierra, something approximating this is:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys backupd
```

However there's a lot of noise from the backup volume itself that I haven't figured out how to get rid of.

Comment: I get a lot of lines like `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 5 (ID 161: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #11 at DIF offset 24` but nothing else.

Comment: For anyone on High Sierra, add `grep` to the second command to get a decent list of only files: `sudo fs_usage -f filesys backupd | grep -oi "HFS_update"`

Comment: On Sierra, `sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys backupd | grep HFS_update` works for me (and gets the full path for deep files/folders).

Comment: Here's a quick [shell script](https://github.com/vegerot/bin/blob/master/tmProgress.sh) I made in about 3 minutes that'll automatically print out each NEW file that is being read.  So instead of getting a bunch of duplicate lines printed out over and over again, it'll only print the files once.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [timedog](https://github.com/nlfiedler/timedog) for that.

> timedog is a Perl script that displays the set of files that were saved for any given backup created by Mac OS X Time Machine. By default it shows those files that were saved in the most recent backup. The listing includes the file sizes before and after, as well as a total file count and size. The script includes an option to summarize changes to a particular directory depth, producing a more concise display, helping to get an understanding of which areas of your system are taking up the most space in the backups. It can also sort by size, and/or omit files below a given size.

Comment: works well, even with AirportExpress attached storage.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to watch which files are being transfered in realtime you can monitor the time machine daemon with

```
sudo fs_usage -f -R filesys backupd
```

If you see abnoramly large file transfer you might see disk images from virtual machines in the list

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `sudo fs_usage -f filesys -R backupd` instead... I'll check it out once I connect to my home network)

Comment: That throws an `Can't open RAW file: No such file or directory` error, the man pages have an example like this `fs_usage -w -f filesys Mail`

Answer (score 6):

I combined the above tmutil answer by BMIKE into this handy one-liner, hopefully it can help someone!

This will take the last 2 backups, and diff them for you. The sed is to put quotes around the backup names which will probably have spaces in them.

```
sudo tmutil listbackups | tail -2 | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs  sudo tmutil compare
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Big Sur using APFS backups to sparesimage.

Answer (score 3):

I really like this commercial software [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) for analysing my backups.

[image]

Comment: warning: paid software

Comment: @alexus Thanks. Included it in the answer. Not sure if commercial software warrants a "warning" ;) I like to pay for good software that simplifies my life.

Comment: nothing wrong w/ commercial software) i say developer should be paid for his/her work) just a fair warning for everyone to know!

Answer (score 0):

For me, on **MacOS Ventura**, the following code line works as a charme to show only files written to the backup disk:

```
sudo fs_usage -f -R filesys backupd | grep RdData
```

Comment: someone before you, already shared this very answer...

Comment: Well, I added only the filter with the grep. Might be better as a comment, agree ...